# How to do arbitrate operation(minus) using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete all relationships which existed more than 2 hours in the system.

I am adding property timestamp each time I create relationship.

I am trying to create a schedule process which deleting all relationship which their created date  is longer than 2 hours.

So I am looking for something like this:

*assume reportDate is timestamp in mili's
*7200000 - 2 hours in milli's

```
match (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
where (r.reportDate - 1447073161751) > 7200000
delete r
```

It didnt work. error from Cypher:

```
Don't know how to Subtract(r.reportDate,{  AUTOINT0}) `1447073161751` with `1447090476190`
```

how i should adjust my where clauses to match my requirement ?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How values at reportDate looks like?
What is represented by `1447073161751`?
What is datatype of reportDate?

- If it's string you need to convert to `int` by `TOINT()`

Try select node first:

```
MATCH (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
WHERE (r.reportDate - 1447073161751) > 7200000 
RETURN p1, r, p2
```

That Cypher works for me without any problem.

Here is the example, which I tried:

**Version with string datatype**

Create

```
CREATE (p1:C9)-[r:follow {reportDate: "123"}]->(p2:C9)
```

Delete

```
MATCH (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
WHERE (TOINT(r.reportDate) - 100) > 20 
DELETE r
```

Check

```
MATCH (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
WHERE (TOINT(r.reportDate) - 100) > 20 
RETURN r
```

**Version with integer datatype**

Create

```
CREATE (p1:C9)-[r:follow {reportDate: 123}]->(p2:C9)
```

Delete

```
MATCH (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
WHERE (r.reportDate - 100) > 20 
DELETE r
```

Check

```
MATCH (p1:C9)-[r:follow]->(p2:C9) 
WHERE (r.reportDate - 100) > 20 
RETURN r
```

Comment: 1447073161751 is timestamp (long)

Comment: And it didnt work out: error msg: Don't know how to Subtract(r.reportDate,{  AUTOINT0}) `1447073161751` with `1447090476190`

Comment: @rayman: I updated my answer. Your problem is probably with datatype of reportDate, because it's not a number. It's probably a string, that's the reason why you got Subtract error.

Comment: if I run this query every 2 mins on all relationships in my Graph. that going to cause performances issues? I must implement expiry service that will delete old-relationships